# Rails 5 select from two different tables and get one result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have 3 models, `Shop`, `Client`, `Product`.

A shop has many clients, and a shop has many products.

Then I have 2 extra models, one is `ShopClient`, that groups the `shop_id` and `client_id`. The second is `ShopProduct`, that groups the `shop_id` and `product_id`.

Now I have a controller that receives two params, the `client_id` and `product_id`. So I want to select all the shops (in one instance variable `@shops`) filtered by `client_id` and `product_id` without shop repetition. How can I do this??

I hope I was clear, thanks.

ps: I'm using Postgresql as database.

Comment: Did one of these answers meet your needs?

Comment: @jvillian, this is works for me: shops = Shop.joins(:shop_clients).where(shop_clients: {client_id: params[:client_id]}).merge(Shop.joins(:shop_products).where(shop_products: {product_id: params[:product_id]}))

Answer (score 5):

Below query will work for you.

```
class Shop
  has_many :shop_clients
  has_many :clients, through: :shop_clients
  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :products, through: :shop_products
end

class Client
end

class Product
end


class ShopClient
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :client
end

class ShopProduct
  belongs_to :shop
  belongs_to :product
end

@shops = Shop.joins(:clients).where(clients: {id: params[:client_id]}).merge(Shop.joins(:products).where(products: {id: params[:product_id]}))
```

Comment: ERROR:  column shops.client_id does not exist. And it is true becaus the table shops does not have a client_id, cause it is saved in the shop_clients table. HOw can I make it works?

Comment: You need to declare has_many association with shop_clients model and then declare has_many clients through shop_clients as stated in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like the best way to solve this issue is to use sub-queries. I'll first collect all valid shop ids from *ShopClient*, followed by all valid shop ids from *ShopProduct*. Than feed them into the where query on *Shop*. This will result in one SQL query.

```
shop_client_ids = ShopClient.where(client_id: params[:client_id]).select(:shop_id)
shop_product_ids = ShopProduct.where(product_id: params[:product_id]).select(:shop_id)
@shops = Shop.where(id: shop_client_ids).where(id: shop_product_ids)

#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Shop id: 1, created_at: "2018-02-14 20:22:18", updated_at: "2018-02-14 20:22:18">]>
```

The above query results in the SQL query below. I didn't specify a limit, but this might be added by the fact that my dummy project uses SQLite.

```
SELECT  "shops".* 
FROM "shops" 
WHERE 
  "shops"."id" IN (
    SELECT "shop_clients"."shop_id" 
    FROM "shop_clients" 
    WHERE "shop_clients"."client_id" = ?) AND 
  "shops"."id" IN (
    SELECT "shop_products"."shop_id" 
    FROM "shop_products" 
    WHERE "shop_products"."product_id" = ?) 
LIMIT ?  
[["client_id", 1], ["product_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 11]]
```

**Combining the two sub-queries in one *where* doesn't result in a correct response:**

```
@shops = Shop.where(id: [shop_client_ids, shop_product_ids])
#=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Produces the query:

```
SELECT  "shops".* FROM "shops" WHERE "shops"."id" IN (NULL, NULL) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

#### note

Keep in mind that when you run the statements one by one in the console this will normally result in 3 queries. This is due to the fact that the return value uses the *#inspect* method to let you see the result. This method is overridden by Rails to execute the query and display the result.

You can simulate the behavior of the normal application by suffixing the statements with `;nil`. This makes sure `nil` is returned and the *#inspect* method is not called on the where chain, thus not executing the query and keeping the chain in memory.

#### edit

If you want to clean up the controller you might want to move these sub-queries into model methods (inspired by [jvillians answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48795866/3982562)).

```
class Shop
  # ...
  def self.with_clients(*client_ids)
    client_ids.flatten! # allows passing of multiple arguments or an array of arguments
    where(id: ShopClient.where(client_id: client_ids).select(:shop_id))
  end
  # ...
end
```

#### Rails sub-query vs join

The advantage of a sub-query over a join is that using joins might end up returning the same record multiple times if you query on a attribute that is not unique. For example, say a product has an attribute *product_type* that is either `'physical'` or `'digital'`. If you want to select all shops selling a digital product you must not forget to call *distinct* on the chain when you're using a join, otherwise the same shop may return multiple times.

However if you'll have to query on multiple attributes in product, and you'll use multiple helpers in the model (where each helper `joins(:products)`). Multiple sub-queries are likely slower. (Assuming you set `has_many :products, through: :shop_products`.) Since Rails reduces all joins to the same association to a single one. Example: `Shop.joins(:products).joins(:products)` (from multiple class methods) will still end up joining the *products* table a single time, whereas sub-queries will not be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Just to riff on the answer provided by Prince Bansal. How about creating some class methods for those joins? Something like:

```
class Shop
  has_many :shop_clients
  has_many :clients, through: :shop_clients
  has_many :shop_products
  has_many :products, through: :shop_products

  class << self 

    def with_clients(clients)
      joins(:clients).where(clients: {id: clients})
    end

    def with_products(products)
      joins(:products).where(products: {id: products})
    end

  end 

end
```

Then you could do something like:

```
@shops = Shop.with_clients(params[:client_id]).with_products(params[:product_id])
```

By the way, I'm sure someone is going to say you should make those class methods into scopes. And you certainly can do that. I did it as class methods because that's what [the Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#passing-in-arguments) recommends:

> Using a class method is the preferred way to accept arguments for scopes.

But, I realize some people strongly prefer the aesthetics of using scopes instead. So, whichever pleases you most.

Comment: ERROR: column shops.client_id does not exist. And it is true becaus the table shops does not have a client_id, cause it is saved in the shop_clients table. HOw can it make it works?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't actually check Prince Bansal's query. I think something like the updated answer *should* work. But, I didn't test. So, you may have to fiddle with it a bit.

Comment: The helpers should be: `joins(:shop_clients).where(shop_clients: {client_id: clients})` or `joins(:clients).where(clients: {id: clients})`. The same for the other helper. The current solution will use a join and a sub-query.

Comment: Thank you, @JohanWentholt. That's quite a bit better.

Comment: @matQ - If you still get the error you might need to set `has_many :clients, through: :shop_clients` on *Shop* or use `joins(:shop_clients).where(shop_clients: {client_id: clients})` instead. The same goes for *Product*.

Answer (score 0):

Below sql query possibly gonna work for you.

```
-- 
-- assuming 
-- tables: shops, products, clients, shop_products, shop_clients
--  

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM shops
  JOIN shop_products 
    ON shop_products.shop_id = shops.id
  JOIN shop_clients 
    ON shop_clients.shop_id = shops.id
WHERE  shop_clients.client_id = ? AND shop_products.product_id = ?
```

If you'll face difficulties while creating an adequate AR expression for this sql query, let me know.

[Btw, here is a mock](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b40fb/3)